# The motion blur is no longer working in my post-processing effects

Tags: unity, graphic-effects, post-processing, blur

I'm using Unity 2019.3.7f1 to create a game. Some time ago I used the post-processing effects v2 package to add motion blur to my game, and it was working. Since then, I disabled these effects while I was developing my game.

Now I'm in the last development phase and I re-enabled my post-processing effects. I however noticed that the motion blur no longer works, although the other post-processing effects are working well.

I cannot figure out why this happens. I'm using a classic rendering, not HDR or something like that. As I said the other effects (e.g. bloom) are working well. I heard that the motion blur needs motion vector to work well, but I cannot find where a such option may be enabled, in order to check it.

Someone has an idea why this happens, and what I should do to fix that?

Comment: When you say "classic rendering", do you mean the built-in render pipeline, rather than one of the scriptable render pipelines like HDRP or URP?

Comment: yes, I mean the built-in pipeline.

Comment: @Jean-MilostReymond did you find a solution to this?